# Two forms one submit button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have two forms, I want to use both forms at the same time.I know it is possible using ajax.

**Form1**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
<label for="url">Enter URL:</label>
<input type="text" name="url" size="35" /><br/>
<label for="filemam">File Name:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="filenam" size="35" />

<br/> <input type="submit" name="sut" value="Submit" />


</form>
```

**Form2**

```
    <form method="post" action="forum2_add_:user-prvar-7890:.xhtml:admin-hash-amp:"> <div id="bb"><br/> <img src="http://scodec.xtgem.com/400px-Warning_icon.svg_.png" width="20" height="20"/> <b><font color="#696969">Avoid All Capital Letter on your thread title, special character like (') is not allowed.**</font></b><br/> <b>Thread Title:</b> <input type="text" name="tema_nazov" value="" maxlength="200"/></div> <div id="bb"><br/><b><font color="#696969"> <img src="http://scodec.xtgem.com/400px-Warning_icon.svg_.png" width="20" height="20"/> Article content should be easy to read, easy to understand,presentation clear in order to attract readers.</font></b><br/><b>Content:</b> <br/> <textarea name="text" rows="5"></textarea> 





<input type="hidden" name="d_token" value="" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="conti()" style="margin:2px"/></div></form>

</div></div>
```

**Note:**

1. I want to run form1 as Javascript
2. I want to run form2 submit button as onclick.

   Anyone?

Comment: If you have a form control named "submit" then you can't call the form's submit method (since *form.submit* now references the control, not the method). There are other issues with your markkup.

Comment: The basics for plain JS XMLHttpRequest are covered pretty well on [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). It's really not hard, and there are plenty of small libraries to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function conti(){
  $("form").first().submit();
}
```

Comment: Provide  solution with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Give form 2 an id and create a js submit event handler for this form that will serialize the form data and send it to the form action, the function will be called on form 2 submit button, what we are doing is preventing the default submit action, and submitting our form through AJAX :

Add id to form 2 :

```
<form method="post" id="formTwo" ....
```

Create a submit function event handler for form two, call AJAX function without the need for onclick event on submit button in form 2 :

```
$("#formTwo").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //

     form = $(this);
     $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
      } );
});
```

Form 1 will submit in its default behavior through its own submit button.